# Linux routing - hop server on same subnet

Tags: networking, routing, ipsec, forwarding

Im trying to get a very simple setup to work,

I have 2 AWS ec2 instances (blue),

instance B has a Ipsec VPN into our datacenter and can ping internal IPs of this datacenter, ie server C (192.168.40.21)

[image]

I need ec2 A instance to be able to ping and connect to server C by using B as a hop. Both A and B are on same subnet. I tried adding B's IP as a gateway on A,

```
  root@A>  ip route add 192.168.40.0/24 via 172.25.25.200
```

and also setup firewall rules on B to forward traffic (sysctl ip4 forwarding = 1),

```
root@B>
iptables -A FORWARD -s 0/0 -d 172.25.25.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 172.25.25.0/24 -d 0/0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 0/0 -s 172.25.25.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

But I cannot ping C from A. What am I missing?

All hosts are Centos 7.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you add the reverse route on C to send packets to A via B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EC2 instances by default have source/destination checking enabled on their network interfaces which means they won't work as routers until you disable it. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html#EIP_Disable_SrcDestCheck

Comment: ha that was it! 

Thanks for pointing this out, I removed SrcDest check from EC2 instance, and now I can forward w/o using GRE tunnel.

would've never caught that by myself!

Answer (score 0):

Usually `iptables` have standard rule for block forwarding traffic. You should remove it to allow traffic pass.

You should remove rule:

```
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Answer (score 0):

Are your instances allowed to communicate on intended ports inside subnet explicitly using Security Groups?

As I did this assumption myself I must suspect this, ec2 instances within the same subnet/SecurityGroup are not able to communicate out of the box without adding the necessary rules as pointed here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=77771

If you've already carefully added the appropriate rules, then maybe you can try looking at the flow of packets using `tcpdump` and filtering on appropriate interface?

Comment: Yes, I opened up both A and B to Allow All on the security groups. 

I think the problem is with my route from A to B, running tcpdump on B, its not showing anytthing coming in from B


`root@A > ip route get 192.168.40.21 is showing the correct gateway (B is the gateway)

root@ip-172-25-25-100 /h/centos# ip route get 192.168.40.21
192.168.40.21 via 172.25.25.200 dev eth0 src 172.25.25.100 
    cache 


root@ip-172-25-25-100 /h/centos# ping 192.168.40.21
PING 192.168.40.21 (192.168.40.21) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a GRE tunnel to route all traffic via server B

the tunnel is between A and B, on A I also add a route to route all traffic for C via GRE tunnel

so it works like this,
A > gre tun > B > ipsec vpn tun > C

** note, see comment above about source/dest check on EC2 instances.